# How to modify a table in a database sent (or ship) in the application without deleting the other tables?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, assets

I'm working on an Android application that use a DB sent in the assets folder. Periodically, I need to update one of the tables in the database, but without deleting the contents of the others (because they had data from the user).

I have read that increasing the version of DB will upgrade the entire DB, but that means resetting every single table.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Unless you need to do joins between the static and user-generated tables, I'd keep 'em in totally separate databases. That simplifies your use of tools like `SQLiteAssetHelper` to maintain the static data without messing up the other tables. And, with `ATTACH DATABASE`, it might even be possible to do the joins between the databases -- I just haven't tried that.

Comment: In fact I need to do joins between tables, but if there isn't another solution, I can make some changes in my design to work with tables separately. I'll try to use **ATTACH DATABASE** first and if I fail, then I'll change my design. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done what **CommonsWare** recommended: to separate databases.  I changed my design so right now I have two different databases (one containing the application information and the other containing the user information). 
With this I'm able to update application DB without deleting user information.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it internally, I'm not sure what triggers your need to update the table, the initial setup of the app or later in your processing.  The process is sort of rudimentary.

Let's say table A has data and you want to add 'col_new' to it.

DROP TABLE Temp

ALTER TABLE A RENAME TO Temp

Drop table A

Create table A with all the columns Table A has plus the 'col_new'.

Query table Temp and insert it into the A table something like this

```
insert into A (name, phonenumber) select name, address from Temp
```

Check that your counts match for both the tables.  Set col_new as you may.

It's probably not what you wanted to hear, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, let me explain it a little different. My App use information from 3 different tables in a DB originally shipped when user downloads the app. Let’s say Table A, B and C. Then on runtime, more tables are created with data entered by the user. The problem comes when I need to add more records to the original tables (A, B and C tables), because so far, I need to increase the DB version and “reload” it from Asset folder, but this lead to erase all other tables in the DB… 
Any way, I find your suggestion very interesting; I will try to see if I can use it in any way to get this done. Thank you!

Comment: Does the content provider from the original app have URI's with crud options?

Comment: No, it doesn't have URI's. I solved the problem as CommonsWare first recommended. Thanks!